# Running Lightning Node without Bitcoin node

Tags: bitcoin-core, lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon

Is there a way to run Lightning Node without any kind of Bitcoin node on your local machine? If not, is there a way for me to run without installing a full node? If any of this approach is possible, what is best software I should use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Lightning Node communicate with Bitcoin node?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/117024/how-does-lightning-node-communicate-with-bitcoin-node)

Comment: P.S. This website wasn't designed for sharing software recommendations and so it isn't suitable for that part of your question.

Comment: Not entirely. I wanted to know what implementation of LN use lightweight client instead of full node.

Comment: See https://www.google.com/search?q=lightning+network+client+software+for+spv+nodes which returns a similar q here and a mention of BLW